# Start service on boot with notification?

Tags: android, service, checkbox, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I have a notification that starts with a service..this service starts when the checkbox in the preferences in checked. (It's a checkboxpreferences)..the problem is that the service when the device boot not starts even if the checkbox is checked. Right now I have to uncheck and check again to start the notification.how can I resolve the problem?

Comment: you need to implement bradcast reciever for your problem....braodcast will call your service on boot of the device

Comment: check this for reference http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: Register a boot broadcast receiver that will start your service!
Also check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android

Comment: but this receiver has to "control" the checkboxpreference state right?

Comment: you can use SharedPreferences or db to store the state of teh checkbox.

Comment: but my service has already a receiver..i mean, the notification is for determinate the battery level..so the receiver is on battery changed...can i do both?

Comment: this is what is written now in the manifest: `<receiver android:name="com.dd.batterystats.MyscheduleReceiver">
- <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  <service android:name="service" />` 
what you mean is write `<receiver android:name="com.dd.batterystats.MyscheduleReceiver">
- <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" />  <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />     
  </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  <service android:name="service" />` ? two receiver?